# how to check whether the string before specific part of a sentence matches with any of the text in other lines or no (same with after specific part)?

Tags: python, function, text

I am trying to check whether the text before first space matches with other lines or no. If they are matching I would like to print only once. Like wise, I would like to check with text after first space. If anything duplicates then print only once.

Input.txt

```
My school name: AVS school
Her school name: AVS school
My school name: ABC school
Their school name: XYZ school
```

output.csv

```
My        school name: AVS school
          school name: ABC school
Their     school name: XYZ school
```

Logic is it should consider how many schools does the first consists. So My consists of 2 schools names and the word 'My' is repeated so we print My only once and school name is unique so we have to print 2 names. In the second line though the starting word is unique school name is already repeated so ignore. The last line is uniques so print it. Finally, I would like to first part in the column and school name in the column.

Tried

```
with open ('input.txt', 'r') as f, open ('output.txt', 'w') as o:
    for line in f:
        a = f.split(' ', 1)
        if line in a:
            print (a[0])
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What would be the output if you add "My school name: DEF school" after the last line?

Comment: @BeChillertoo It would be  [My        school name: AVS school
                                                         school name: ABC school
                                                         school name: DEF school                                                                             
                                            Their     school name: XYZ school] I mean school name: DEF school should be below the ABC school name

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

s = """My school name: AVS school
Her school name: AVS school
My school name: ABC school
Their school name: XYZ school
My school name: DEF school"""

sentences = collections.defaultdict(list)

unique_suffixes = set()

for line in s.split('\n'):
    start, end = line.split(' ', maxsplit=1)
    if end not in unique_suffixes:
        unique_suffixes.add(end)
        sentences[start] += [end]

# Displaying the results
for start, ends in sentences.items():
    print(start, ends[0])
    for end in ends[1:]:
        print(len(start)*'-', end)
```

## Displays

```
My school name: AVS school
-- school name: ABC school
-- school name: DEF school
Their school name: XYZ school
```

### Warning

This dictionary is not ordered, so you could have "Their" then "My":

```
Their school name: XYZ school
My school name: AVS school
-- school name: ABC school
-- school name: DEF school
```

Comment: how can we keep this in .csv for at to print the first part in one column and second part in the other

Comment: I did not understand your question.